# URL Connection Refused

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

When I run my JSP project local, this code works:

```
new URL("http://www.example.com").openConnection().getInputStream();
```

When I upload my project to a `webserver`, I am getting this exception for the code above:

```
Connection refused
```

I am confused about this because another method that also uses an URL is working fine on the `webserver`, this one:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

The URL that is given in the parameters are correct. I can browse to them directly via the browser on my laptop.

I would like to know why the first URL doesn't work on the webserver, and the second one does? And why does the first URL work when running the project local?

The webserver is a Tomcat server.

I checked this thread already: [What is a work around for Connection refused: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388138/what-is-a-work-around-for-connection-refused-connect)

Comment: do you have web browser's proxy configured ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Hello, I am using Google Chrome, and never used a proxy nor configured it.

Comment: Check if you need to set some specific HTTP headers

Comment: Check if your webserver has internet connection. And you can connect to that website from that server (not just your computer)

Comment: @Artem It has internet connection, otherwise the provided second example wouldn't work.

Comment: It is strange because the javadoc or URL class (JDK 7) says for `openStream` *Opens a connection to this URL and returns an InputStream for reading from that connection. This method is a shorthand for:

         openConnection().getInputStream()*. Are you really connecting to same URL ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta The first url (which doesn't work) is a URL that belongs to the same domain name as the website, the second URL (second example) is an external URL. But when I visit my own URL (first one) via the browser then it works..

Comment: So the problem should be on the proxies or firewalls of the server. You'd better ask the question to the servers administrator (there may be a lot of causes for such an error, from misconfiguration to essential security reasons).