# how to click the link in jsp page from another page

Tags: jsp

I have two jsp pages like test1.jsp and test2.jsp page. Test1.jsp is deployed in tomcat server1 and test2.jsp is deployed in server2. Now I am redirecting user from server1 jsp to server2 jsp page and to click the link in server2 jsp page explicitly.

```
Example:

test2.jsp in server2
<html>
<head><title>First JSP</title></head>
<body>
 <a href="http://www.test.com">Try Again</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I need to click the try again link explicitly when user enter this page.

NOTE: I cant change the code of test2.jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you don't need to display the test2.jsp at all. You need only the url, which is in test2.jsp.

If my assumptions are right, the algorithm could be:

- read the test2.jsp code inside of test1.jsp
- Extract the url and
- redirect.

This can be done with:

- [`<c:import>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakn) (in JSP+JSTL)
- [`HttpURLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (in JSP+Scriptlet/Servlet/Class)
- [`HtmlUnit`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) (in JSP+Scriptlet/Servlet/Class)

**With `<c:import>` in JSP:**

If you want to do that in jsp the code (without the parsing) could be:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:import url="http://server2/test2.jsp" var="test2Data"></c:import>
<%-- extract the url from test2Data and redirect --%>
```

The parsing could be done in custom tag, if the test2.jsp is static and not changing often.

**With HttpURLConnection:**

You can use [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) in a JSP scriptlet or Servlet to open the test2.jsp, then parse and returns the url only.

**With HtmlUnit:**

If the URL in test2.jsp are generated by javascript, you can use for example [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

**Even better skip the parsing:**

If the server2 is yours, and you have any control of the url generation, add a servlet there to skip the parsing and get the Url directly from the source.

Comment: I tried above all three methods but I got connection refused error
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:import var="data" url="<%= http://server2/test2.jsp%>"/>
<c:out value="${data}"/>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This look suspicious: `url="<%= server2/test2.jsp%>"`. Use the url as string and not scriptlets.  `server2` ist just placeholder for the real domain.

Comment: sorry!... I tried like 
<%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c" %> <html> <head> <title>Tag Example</title> </head> <body> <c:import var="data" url="http://www.test.com/test.jsp" />; <c:out value="${data}"/> </body> </html>

Comment: Here are few tips how to resolve refused connection error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2388186/1107653

Comment: Server2 have crossorgin, xframe and ip restriction